# Is there a standard for server PSU dimensions?

Tags: power-supply, webserver, dimensions

I don't have a lot of knowledge about server technology, but a simple question which I cannot get an answer for by seraching the internet.

Are server PSUs following a norm in their dimensions (length, width, height)?

Looking at the connectors via image search, which are quite different between brands and models, I get the feeling that the sizes might vary accordingly. Since rack stacking is somewhat normed afaik, some sizes might be limited by these circumstances. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most relevant norm is the RU (rack units). This is respected by all server PSUs. An 2U PSU will never fit physically in the position of a 1U PSU. Weight is not relevant. X x Y are usually 225-230 x 100 while Z is the size RU-related.

Comment: And google told me that the height of a rack unit is 4.445 cm, correct?

Comment: Affirmative. 44.45mm is considered 1U. So 2U will be 88.9 and so forth.